# VichUploaderBundle and AvalancheImagineBundle

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

I use VichUploaderBundle for upload my media files and I want to use AvalancheImagineBundle to create thumbs in my templates.
How it should be done?

I have this right now:

```
<td><img src="{{ vich_uploader_asset(entity, 'image') | apply_filter('my_thumb')}}" alt="{{ entity.nombre }}" /></td>
```

But the output is:

```
<img src="/app_dev.php/media/cache/my_thumb/images/uploads/392158_10150441208223772_580903771_8591661_774015725_n.jpg" alt="Froga"/>
```

this is my config.yml:

```
# Vich Uploader
vich_uploader:
    db_driver: orm
    twig: true
    gaufrette: false # set to true to enable gaufrette support
    storage: vich_uploader.storage.file_system
    mappings:
        uploads:
            uri_prefix: /images/uploads
            upload_destination: %kernel.root_dir%/../web/images/uploads
            namer: ~ # specify a file namer service id for this entity, null default
            directory_namer: ~ # specify a directory namer service id for this entity, null default
            delete_on_remove: true # determines whether to delete file upon removal of entity
            inject_on_load: true # determines whether to inject a File instance upon load

avalanche_imagine:
    source_root:  %kernel.root_dir%/../web/images/uploads
    web_root:     %kernel.root_dir%/../web/images/uploads
    cache_prefix: media/cache
    driver:       gd
    filters:
        my_thumb:
            type:    thumbnail
            options: { size: [120, 90], mode: outbound, quality: 100, format: png }
```

Any help or clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the problem you are having is that no image is being displayed, then I had the same issue.

In order to solve it I ensured that within my config.yml, the `source_root` and `web_root` options of avalanche_imagine were set to `%kernel.root_dir%/../web` (or your web root). Here is the relevant snippet from my config.yml:

```
#Uploads
knp_gaufrette:
    adapters:
        article_adapter:
            local:
                directory: %kernel.root_dir%/../web/images/articles
    filesystems:
        article_image_fs:
            adapter:    article_adapter
vich_uploader:
    db_driver: orm
    gaufrette: true
    storage: vich_uploader.storage.gaufrette
    mappings:
        article_image:
            uri_prefix: /images/articles
            upload_destination: article_image_fs
            namer: vich_uploader.namer_uniqid

#images
avalanche_imagine:
    filters:
        article_list:
            type:    thumbnail
            options: { size: [100, 100], mode: outbound }
    source_root:  %kernel.root_dir%/../web
    web_root:     %kernel.root_dir%/../web
    cache_prefix: cache
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with that. Imagine bundle in production generates thumbnail the first time its called and stores it in web/media folder. On second call it just reads from web/media. 
It has some advantages to modify the thumnail sizes at will. If You are worried about performance you should fire some job to generate thumbnail after the upload is finished,
although i used it like that and never complained.

Comment: but the output it isn´t correct: <img src="/app_dev.php/media/cache/my_thumb/images/uploads/392158_10150441208223772_580903771_8591661_774015725_n.jpg" alt="Froga"/>

Comment: If you are in dev mode it will add app_dev.php. First call generates image, second call and rest is 301 redirect to generated file.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I chose to use `LiipImagineBundle` which is a fork of the `AvalancheImagineBundle`
.

I were configure this bundle to use gaufrette as data-loader, than it simple to use it as you describe, without caring much about the paths.